# Using inversion in conditionals

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Is this sentence correct: Had this happened around the time of mad cow disease, it'd be easier to explain.
Shouldn't this read : Had this happened around the time of mad cow disease, it would have been easier to explain.
Thanks!

Comment: Only if you wanted to explain in the past. If you're talking about explaining now, _would_ (contracted to _'d_, naturally) is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more a question of selecting the right verb tense in a conditional than a question of inversion in a conditional.

> *Had this happened around the time of mad cow disease*

equates to

> *If this had happened around the time of mad cow disease*

Now as for the difference between:

> a. *it would **be** easier to explain*

and

> b. *it would **have been** easier to explain*

If the act of explaining occurred in the past and you care to articulate the pastness of the act, you should go with option b.

If the act of explaining didn't occur in the past, you should go with option a.

If the act of explaining did occur in the past but somehow you don't want to articulate the pastness of the act, you should also go with option a.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation.